# Stop asyntask threads in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpool

I am extending the AsynTask to update the images on screen. The images were updated from input stream through sockets continuously. 
When I press the back button I have come out from the asyn task doinbackground(). After coming from the doinbackground(), I am closing the input stream and socket.

Where I am getting the below exception

```
08-09 20:19:24.410: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
08-09 20:19:24.420: W/System.err(32597):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:448)
08-09 20:19:24.420: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
08-09 20:19:24.420: W/System.err(32597):    at com.einstructions.interwriteworkspace.WorkSpaceActivity$GetImageStreamFromServer.doInBackground(WorkSpaceActivity.java:618)
08-09 20:19:24.430: W/System.err(32597):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
08-09 20:19:24.450: W/System.err(32597):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
08-09 20:19:24.450: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-09 20:19:24.470: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
08-09 20:19:24.480: W/System.err(32597):    at com.einstructions.interwriteworkspace.WorkSpaceActivity$GetImageStreamFromServer.doInBackground(WorkSpaceActivity.java:1)
08-09 20:19:24.480: W/System.err(32597):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
08-09 20:19:24.480: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-09 20:19:24.490: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
08-09 20:19:24.490: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
08-09 20:19:24.490: W/System.err(32597):    at com.einstructions.interwriteworkspace.WorkSpaceActivity$GetImageStreamFromServer.doInBackground(WorkSpaceActivity.java:618)
08-09 20:19:24.500: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-09 20:19:24.500: W/System.err(32597):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
08-09 20:19:24.500: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
08-09 20:19:24.500: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
08-09 20:19:24.510: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
08-09 20:19:24.510: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
08-09 20:19:24.510: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
08-09 20:19:24.520: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
08-09 20:19:24.520: W/System.err(32597):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:448)
08-09 20:19:24.520: W/System.err(32597):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
```

Could please help me

Regards
mini.

Comment: Are you closing the stream first?

Comment: First of all: your stack trace doesn't look complete. Both the name and message of the actual exception is missing as well as the cause of the exception. Second of all: post your complete AsyncTask code.

Answer (score 0):

You must cancel the `GetImageStreamFromServer` task when you pause/stop Activity.
inside onPause/onStop use,

```
getImageStreamFromServerTask.cancel(true);
```